# Add blank line to Ajax-based select box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a set of select boxes that are populated using some Ajax magic. The Ajax loads the select boxes with the correct data, but I'm having trouble with adding a blank line to the top of the combo box. Since the collection doesn't have a blank, neither does the select box.

Here is what the update part of my controller looks like:

```
  def update_select
    @areas = Area.where("product_type_id = ?", params[:product_type_id])
    @products = Product.where("product_type_id = ? AND active = 't'", params[:product_type_id])
    @accessories = Product.where("product_type_id = ? AND active = 't' AND accessory = 't'", params[:product_type_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Here is what is rendered with the update:

```
$("#area_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "select_boxes/area", collection: @areas)) %>")
$("#product_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "select_boxes/product", collection: @products)) %>")
$("#accessory_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "select_boxes/accessory", collection: @accessories)) %>")
```

and here is one of the partials for the select boxes (they are all three basically the same)

```
<option value="<%= accessory.id %>"><%= accessory.product_number %></option>
```

and here is the partial that actually displays the form fields:

```
<tr class="details_row nested-fields">
  <td><%= f.select :area_id, options_for_select(@areas.collect {|c| [ c.area_name, c.id ] }, f.object.area_id), {include_blank: true}, {:id => 'area_select', :class => 'form-control'} %></td>
  <td><%= f.select :product_id, options_for_select(@products.collect {|p| [ p.product_number, p.id ] }, f.object.product_id), {include_blank: true}, {:id => 'product_select', :class => 'form-control'} %></td>
  <td><%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control', "min" => 1 %></td>
  <td><%= f.select :accessory_id, options_for_select(@accessories.collect {|p| [ p.product_number, p.id ] }, f.object.product_id), {include_blank: true}, {:id => 'accessory_select', :class => 'form-control'} %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :notes, class: 'form-control' %></td>
  <td><%= link_to_remove_association '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>'.html_safe, f %></td>
</tr>
```

Is there a simple way to add a blank to the collection before the select boxes are updated? Or is there some way to do this in the partial? I have included the "include_blank: true" in the actual form, but this must be ignored when the select box is updated via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this in the partial using the partial counter I discovered in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)...of all places.... = )

```
<% if accessory_counter == 0 %>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="<%= accessory.id %>"><%= accessory.product_number %></option>
<% else %>
  <option value="<%= accessory.id %>"><%= accessory.product_number %></option>
<% end %>
```